# How to edit characters in a list using python?

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
['01. The A Team.mp3', '02. Drunk.mp3', '03. UNI.mp3', '04. Grade 8.mp3']
```

How can I delete the number part at the beginning of each element (like `01.`, `02.`, etc) and the `.mp3` part at the end of each element?

Comment: `print( '01. The A Team.mp3'[4:-4] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that actually verifies that you're removing what you expect to remove - will need modification if file names you want to change can contain other endings than `.mp3`.

```
import re

def fix_name(name):
    if name.endswith('.mp3'):
        name = name[:-4]

    return re.sub(r'^[0-9]+\. ', '', name)

a = ['01. The A Team.mp3', '02. Drunk.mp3', '03. UNI.mp3', '04. Grade 8.mp3']
print(list(map(fix_name, a)))
```

The regular expression will remove any numbers (`[0-9]+`) followed by a dot and a space (`.`) at the start of the string (`^`).

```
In: ['01. The A Team.mp3', '02. Drunk.mp3', '03. UNI.mp3', '04. Grade 8.mp3']
Out: ['The A Team', 'Drunk', 'UNI', 'Grade 8']
```

`map` applies the function to every element in your list, while `list` is needed to create a list, since we're not iterating over the results from `map` (which is a generator).

Answer (score 0):

You want to subscript your strings. Try something like `[x[4:-4] for x in ['01. The A Team.mp3', '02. Drunk.mp3', '03. UNI.mp3', '04. Grade 8.mp3']]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
old_list = ['01. The A Team.mp3', '02. Drunk.mp3', '03. UNI.mp3', '04. Grade 8.mp3']
new_list = [el.split(".")[1].strip() for el in old_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = ['01. The A Team.mp3', '02. Drunk.mp3', '03. UNI.mp3', '04. Grade 8.mp3']
clean_data = []
for row in data:
    wanted_text = row.split(".")[1].strip()
    clean_data.append(wanted_text)
print(clean_data)
```